# Driving 12V relays from Raspberry Pi

Tags: relay

I want to use a Raspberry Pi to drive [this](http://logi5.xiti.com/go.click?xts=335357&s2=89&p=Range::Zelio%20Solid%20State%20and%20Plug-in%20Relays~532::RSB1A160JDS_pdf_datasheet&clic=T&type=click&url=//www.ops-ecat.schneider-electric.com/cut.CatalogueRetrieverServlet/CatalogueRetrieverServlet?fct=get_element&env=publish&scp_id=Z018&lc=us&el_typ=product&cat_id=BU_AUT_532_L3_Z018&maj_v=1&min_v=33&nod_id=0000000010&prd_id=RSB1A160JDS&frm=pdf&price=9.50%20USD&prc=true&pdf_frm=US&brd_id=null&ecat_url=http://www.ops-ecat.schneider-electric.com/ecatalogue/&isTraining=false&dwnl=true) relay. It is solid state, SP/ST, needs 12V for the coil and can switch up to 16A at 250V AC.

Now, I know that The RPi cannot switch natively anything above 3V and I have already [found](http://www.instructables.com/id/Connecting-a-12V-Relay-to-Arduino/) a circuit doing just that, switching a 12V relay from 5V logic.

My question is this. Is there a better way to do this? I would really like something a bit more "professional" because it will go in the electrical cabinet as part of a permanent installation. Ideally, I think, this should be electrically isolated from the RPi and also have some sort of protection, in the form of a fuse or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi's gpios are 3V3 not 5V.

I couldn't make out from the datasheet the needed current to operate the relay contacts.

Assuming it is less than, say, 250 mA, I'd use a [ULN2003A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) or similar to operate the contacts.  It has in-built fly-back protection and can be operated by the Pi's gpios.

I'm a software type though. There are probably better sites for this sort of question.

Answer (score 3):

I had that same problem for my Pool Timer. Schematic, parts and reasoning are here: http://upon2020.com/blog/2012/12/my-raspberry-pi-pool-timer-electronic-assembly/

It's been working in production for almost 2 years now.

Answer (score 2):

Add a transistor drive step to your relay which in turn switches the high voltage circuit. (but yes you will also need a 12 Volt power supply to drive the relay, a volt relay could be better as you will have that voltage available)

http://apps.usd.edu/coglab/psyc770/transistors101.html

Answer (score 1):

The specification clearly "but mixed in with allot of other things"

[image]

<strike>5ma (300mW) @ 5V</strike> 12V @ 33mA needs to be applied to drive the relay. The GPIO pins them selves wont be able to do it because they are 3.3v. You can solve this by using a logic level shifter like MAX 3370 or [as seen on Sparkies](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/txb0104-level-shifter-hookup-guide)

Comment: Looking at it again it seems to need 33mA at 12V to operate the relay coils (360R coils).  This gives 400mW against the quoted average of 450mW.

Comment: Where do you see that? Damn that must be the worst data sheet ever.

Comment: I was looking at "Control circuit voltage 12 V DC" and "Average coil resistance 360 Ohm (DC) at 20 °C +/- 10 %" and "Average coil consumption 0.45 W DC".  Look at the DHT22 for a bad data sheet contender!

Comment: LOL. That is pretty bad :) OK I updated it. Thanks